# set cookie header in chrome is not working for the following

Tags: session, google-chrome, cookies

the following set cookie header is not working in chrome (working in firefox)
except the life time is set to the **far future** for example (2015-1-1) OR to **remove it completely**

```
Set-Cookie:zii_s=s81d344olng0sfc4lt3ogqsup1; expires=Thu, 18-Oct-2012 18:51:01 GMT; path=/; domain=***; HttpOnly
```

can anyone tell me whats wrong with it and how to walk around it ?